# Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1) in flutter

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-dependencies, cloudways, flutter-apk

I got this error:

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

```
Future<List<banner>> getBannerPictures() async {
  var url = Uri.http('https://woocommerce-811161-3604078.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-json/api/v1/get-home-page');
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.body.toString());
  List<banner> photos = [];
  List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
  print(data.toString());

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    photos.add(banner.fromJson(data[i]));
  }
  return photos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `Uri` constructor.

Either use `Uri.parse`, or use a hostname with path params instead.

So for your code snippet the change would be:

```dart
Future<List<banner>> getBannerPictures() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://woocommerce-811161-3604078.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-json/api/v1/get-home-page');
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.body.toString());
  List<banner> photos = [];
  List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
  print(data.toString());

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    photos.add(banner.fromJson(data[i]));
  }
  return photos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uri.http() requires all separated params (hostname...), see the doc here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html

ex:

```js
var uri = Uri.http('example.org', '/path', { 'q' : 'dart' });
print(uri); // http://example.org/path?q=dart
```

As suggested by Niko, with your entire url, you should use Uri.parse(), see the doc here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/parse.html

ex:

```js
final uri =
    Uri.parse('https://example.com/api/fetch?limit=10,20,30&max=100');
print(uri); // https://example.com/api/fetch?limit=10,20,30&max=100
```